# MySQL trigger results in error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I tried writing this small trigger in MySQL,

```
CREATE TRIGGER `leg` BEFORE INSERT ON `bckoff` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `bckoff` SET `step`=1;
END;
```

after which I get this error.. I'm a newbie to MySQL.. so please help me out here..

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Comment: What does your table look like.  Why is your trigger inserting into the same table you are inserting into?

Comment: wat do u have at line 3?

Comment: Oh! Can I not use triggers on the same table I am inserting into ? I certainly did not know that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after you fix this error - you'll get another one: you cannot modify the table that your trigger was created at.

Btw, this is how you should create this trigger:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER `leg` BEFORE INSERT ON `bckoff` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `bckoff` SET `step`=1;
END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Comment: So is there any way to do that ? What if I *do* want to modify the same table ?

Comment: @Hrishikesh Choudhari: explain the task you're trying to solve with this code.

Comment: I have a "parent" item with an ID. If I create a "child" item with parent ID (say parentID 123), then I want to increment the "children" column for that parent by 1. This is the actual task I'm trying to get done..

Comment: @Hrishikesh Choudhari: well, you could perform 2 queries manually or create a stored procedure that will do all this work (2 quesries) for you.

Comment: Ohk.. I guess then triggers are not suited for the job here.. I'll go learn about stored procedures then.. Thanks zerkms for pointing me in the right direction.. :)